Inlining external jsonschema references with Python
I have a question similar to this one except all I want to do is take external references and inline them.
For example, let's say I have a schema like this one:
{
    "$defs": {
        "JSONSchema": {
            "$ref": "https://json-schema.org/draft/2020-12/schema"
        }
    },
    "properties": {
        "config_1_jsonschema": {
            "$ref": "#/$defs/JSONSchema"
        },
        "config_2_jsonschema": {
            "$ref": "#/$defs/JSONSchema"
        }
    }
}

I have two fields which reference the JSONSchema definition that in turn references a URL to the JSONSchema meta-schema. I would like to dereference the URL, inlining that schema, and recursively inlining all of its external references, but not inlining the local references for the two properties.
How would I go about this while keeping the schema valid? Is there an existing library in Python that would let me do this?

so you only want to dereference the $defs reference?   it's pretty uncommon to use the meta-schema in this way. what are you trying to do with those two properties that they need to use the meta-schema?

I want to embed anything that's a $ref to a URL, so that I have a single file that's a source of truth.

As for my use of the jsonschema schema, those two fields are getting json objects that are jsonschema objects that will be used later for verifying other json documents.

You can safely copy the contents of an external schema into your schema if a few conditions are met.

The external schema must have a $id keyword.
If the external schema uses a different dialect ($schema) from the local schema, the external schema must have a $schema keyword.
You can only inline full schema resources, not sub-schemas.
You'll need to also include any external references from the referenced schema.

In your case, the only tricky part is that last part
{
    "$defs": {
        "JSONSchema": {
            "$ref": "https://json-schema.org/draft/2020-12/schema"
        },
        "draft-2020-12-schema": {
            "$id": "https://json-schema.org/draft/2020-12/schema",
            "$schema": "https://json-schema.org/draft/2020-12/schema",
            ...
            "allOf": [
                { "$ref": "meta/core" },
                { "$ref": "meta/applicator" },
                { "$ref": "meta/unevaluated" },
                { "$ref": "meta/validation" },
                { "$ref": "meta/meta-data" },
                { "$ref": "meta/format-annotation" },
                { "$ref": "meta/content" }
            ],
            ...
        },
        "draft-2020-12-core-vocab": {
            "$id": "https://json-schema.org/draft/2020-12/meta/core",
            "$schema": "https://json-schema.org/draft/2020-12/schema",
            ...
        },
        "draft-2020-12-applicator-vocab": { ... },
        ...
    },
    "properties": {
        "config_1_jsonschema": {
            "$ref": "#/$defs/JSONSchema"
        },
        "config_2_jsonschema": {
            "$ref": "#/$defs/JSONSchema"
        }
    }
}

